# How to delete the documents a month ago

Tags: solr, lucene

We are using Solr 1.4.

How to delete the documents a month ago?

Answer (score 7):

We are doing something similar where we purge items from one of our indexes, using curl and taking advantage of the timestamp field in the Solr schema.

Here is the curl command that you would issue to delete items older than 30 days (using [DateMathParser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/util/DateMathParser.html) to calculate based on current day), using the `timestamp` field in the schema.

```
 curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" 
   --data-binary "<delete><query>timestamp:[* TO NOW/DAY-30DAYS]</query></delete>"
```

Of course you will need to change the url to match your solr instance and you may choose to use a different field.

Also here is the field definition for the timestamp field from the schema.xml that comes with the Solr distribution in the example folder.

```
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work, this is the url string I used: "http://localhost:8080/mcu1fpSE/articleCore/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>PRESENTDATE:[2011-12-01T00:00:00.000Z TO 2011-12-31T23:59:59.999Z]</query></delete>'". I've encoded it and then issue the url. Later I use facet to see the result, there' s still non-zero count on 2011-12 item, What's wrong?

Comment: On double retry, I qurey for data of 2011-12 but there's none. However, the facet still shows 250 counts of data. I think Solr's facet query has bug? (note: I've stop and re-start the solr base and the inconsistency still exists. By the way, I use Solr v3.3)

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number of documents to say 200K

Answer (score 5):

You need to POST in order to do deletes but if you use the post.jar from the example folder in the installation it is simply:

```
java -Ddata=args -Dcommit=yes -jar post.jar "<delete><query>$DateField:[* TO $DateOneMonthAgo]</query></delete>"
```

where $DateField is the name of the field where the date is stored and $DateOneMonthAgo is the date one month from now (2011-11-09T11:48:00Z)